# Genre similar to instrumental version of "Elder Brothers" (ambient piano, OD electric guitar)

Tags: identify-this-genre, instrumental, piano, guitar

I would really love to identify a genre of songs that are ambient and instrumental, with piano, maybe some slight overdriven electric guitar that has room-type reverb and delays, just picking some soft lead.

I have an example though the band has a singer: [Elder Brothers - Greatest Hit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_WiBlVyneM)

I love the band and have been listening to them for a few but I would really want something similar to their style, but instrumental.  If there are any bands or playlists on YouTube in this genre, I would love to find them.

Comment: I edited this slightly to make it a genre-identification question.  Those are on-topic here, whereas recommendation questions are not.  With that said, you might really enjoy the *Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind* soundtrack, at least [the instrumental tracks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC0CaGSwme0).

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily a genre *per se*, but there are plenty of hits for "ambient piano," although a lot of them are more uptempo that what you are looking for.  I modified it as ["sad ambient piano"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoSridCnqN8) and "[slow ambient piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbPL13Y0vOc)" and got [some songs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vohFxJ982Ic) that sounded pretty close.

You might also enjoy the [Jon Brion instrumentals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC0CaGSwme0) on the *Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind* soundtrack.  They are not quite as ambient, but they do have that melancholy piano sound.