# What genre is Old School Runescape's (MMORPG) "Book of Spells"?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

I am looking for music similar to *Old School Runescape*'s (MMORPG) soundtrack, "Book of Spells."

These are two versions of this song:--

- (

  )
- (

  )

---

**Questions**:--

What genre(s) of music does this song belong to?

What modern or old composers is this song inspired by?

**Note**:-

I do not play MMORPGs.

---

*Prior Research*:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_synth)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_ambient)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_music)
- (https://oldschoolrunescape.fandom.com/wiki/Music)

Comment: I agree with the edits by Chris Sunami (user). I was aiming at a serious goal, but I had issues with the formatting and style.  I decided to put this question: "What modern or old composers is this song inspired by?", back in, because that part was not redundant. Best wishes, and thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call the piano versions "melancholy piano", which may not be an official genre, but perhaps should be one.

For songs with a similar feel I'd recommend:

- [Gymnopedies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-Xm7s9eGxU) - Erik Satie
- [*Eternal Sunshine* soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC0CaGSwme0) - Jon Brion
- [John, I Love You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmkdPh-Ms60) - Sinead O'Connor

All personal favorites of mine, by the way.  You might also see [this similar question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6708/genre-similar-to-instrumental-version-of-elder-brothers-ambient-piano-od-ele/6710#6710) for more suggestions.

The original *Ultima* song is perhaps best described as "Celtic New Age" --like [Enya](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKQwgpaLR6o).  The *Runescape* original doesn't have the same Celtic flavor, so I'd just go with "[melancholy New Age](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHS0QEPQuLs)" music for the genre.

Answer (score 0):

*Ultima VII: The Black Gate* has a similar soundtrack.

While I am not 100% certain, it is reasonable to conclude that [*Runescape* was probably influenced by *Ultima*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Western_role-playing_video_games#Ultima_and_Wizardry_(early%E2%80%93mid-1980s)). (I can't find a source directly linking the two songs.)

- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CM_1m8ZgdJw)
- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCRqSbV_vo0)